# Eyes begin to strain on 4k@60hz on Linux compared to MacOs, what to do?

Tags: linux, drivers, xorg, hardware, display

**I am working on Macbook Pro (mid 2015) connected to dual Dell P2514Q (via DisplayPort 1.2). It gives wonderful 4k@60hz, I enjoy the picture**. However recently I installed Linux on the same macbook (Linux Mint) and configured it to give me 4k@60hz. And here is the problem - it looks all good, scaling, texts, all looks good. **It reports that the frequency is 60Hz, however my eyes notable get strained**.

**I would suspect the cable or the Intel GPU, but since MacOS (Catalina) works just fine, then I must blame something about how Linux video system works.**

Is there anything I could tune about the frequency? Maybe in fact it report 60Hz but outputs 55 or something, I don't know. Pulling my hair off as I have no idea where to look for a solution.

Please advice.

p.s. Windows 10 connected to the same display seems to be as comfortable as MacOs.

p.p.s
Here is a video of my display: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGGlH5lbISc

1. Left: MacOs Catalina
2. Right: Linux Mint

p.p.p.s Added photos of screen - MacOs and Linux.

[image]
[image]

Here [contents](https://products.groupdocs.app/editor/edit?folderName=c448a2fd-30ab-48fe-8a72-1d6570699998&fileName=Xorg.0.log.txt) of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

**update**: it can be related to the dithering effect (see https://ledstrain.org/d/785-eyestrain-when-switching-from-windows-to-linux/32)

Comment: Assuming you run X and not Wayland, first step is to look at `/var/log/Xorg.log.0` to see which mode actually gets set. I cannot make out any difference in your video. Is it possible that the difference is not refresh frequency, but e.g. non-aliased font-rendering? Have you tried to take a close-up photo of the screen?

Comment: "I cannot make out any difference in your video" - me too. The difference is not easily visible, it is just a discomfort in the eyes. Added photos and log file just to put extra context in here.

Comment: You are getting a 3840x2160 mode, but for some reason the AMD driver doesn't log if it's the 30Hz or the 60Hz one. Try `xrandr`, and if that doesn't give the frequency, `xrandr --verbose`. Also, the MacOS fonts seem to be slightly more bold than the Linux fonts; could that be the reason, because the bolder fonts are easier on your eyes?

Comment: When you run `lshw` as root, what shows up for the display (under `pci:0 --> display`)? Can you add the whole output of the `display` section to your question?

Comment: There are known incompatibilities between the eyes of Mac users and free software like Linux. You must upgrade your eyes. Did you try [the latest patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyepatch)?